# vba instr and redim to replace string with another value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, formula

Really struggling here!
I would like to replace each extracted number with a new value.
Currently my code replaces only the first grouped number before a delimiter but it does not return to the same cell to carry out the same for the other numbers.

I would want each holder to NOT go into another cell, rather that the values be replaced.
Here is my code below

```
enter code here
    Sub match2()
    Dim count As Long, count1 As Long
    Dim holder As String, SNL_ID As String
    Dim sample As String, smallSample  As String, S_doc As String, a_label As String, m_label As String
    Dim LastRowa As Long, mrow As Long, x As Long, Arow As Long, v As Long, srow As Long, y As Long, SNL_val As String
    Dim Speriod As Date


    'If AG mappping label = AG label then copy and paste results in column A


        mrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To mrow
        m_label = Sheet1.Cells(x, "C").Value
        S_doc = "FRY-9C"

        Arow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For v = 2 To Arow
        a_label = Sheet2.Cells(v, "N").Value

        srow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For y = 2 To srow
        SNL_ID = Sheet3.Cells(y, "H").Value
        SNL_val = Sheet3.Cells(y, "H").Value


        If a_label = m_label & Worksheets("Mapping").Range(x, "M").Value = S_doc Then
            Worksheets("Mappings").Activate
            Worksheets("Mappings").Cells(x, 10).copy
            Worksheets("AG").Select
            Worksheets("AG").Cells(v, "A").PasteSpecial
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        End If
        Next y
        Next v
        Next x

    count = 0
    LastRowa = Worksheets("Match2").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With Sheet4
        For i = 1 To LastRowa
        count1 = 3
        holder = ""
        sample = Worksheets("Match2").Range("C" & i).Value

        Do While count <> Len(sample)
            smallSample = Left(sample, 1)
            If smallSample = "0" Or smallSample = "1" Or smallSample = "2" Or smallSample = "3" Or smallSample = "4" Or smallSample = "5" Or smallSample = "6" Or smallSample = "7" Or smallSample = "8" Or smallSample = "9" Then
                holder = holder & smallSample
                If InStr(holder, SNL_ID) > 0 Then
                holder = holder & SNL_val
            Else
                If holder <> "" Then
                  'Cells(i, count1) = holder
                  count1 = holder + 1
                End If
                holder = ""
            End If
            End If
            'If Len(sample) = 1 Then Cells(i, count1) = holder
            'sample = (Right(sample, Len(sample) - 1))
        Loop
        Next i
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: It would really help if you could include a small sample dataset.  Show us what your spreadsheet looks like before the code has run.  And then show us what you'd like it to look like once the code has run.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It will help with reading it. Also, declare all variables at the top. mrow, Arow, srow,S_doc etc can all be assigned at the top. Can you clarify your question with an example of what you expected and what happened?

Comment: here is a sample of the cells where the number values should be replaced. 209474 + 209475
206550 + 206551 + 206553 + 206554 + 206555

Comment: I think I've fixed you indentation.. I think!. Saying that, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. I'm Also not sure as to what your code is trying to achieve. I would suggest that you start from scratch.. Breakdown your requirements and start inside out. At the moment you have a lot of bad practices in your code which are possibly confusing the issue. i.e. You nested `FOR` loops don't make any sense to me specially considering the fact that you never use `y`. Also what @Mat'sMug commented on

Comment: @Zac  Im obviously very new to this so I really appreciate your help. I have rephrased the question above for clarity